# Using childrens in React Container

Tags: reactjs

Can I use children in React Container or is it wrong?
For example, I have a list of buttons(`ActionButton`) that are grouped together (`ActionMenu`).

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ActionMenu>
        <ActionButton name="New" icon="add" />
        <ActionButton name="Delete" icon="remove" />
      </ActionMenu>
    )
  }
}

class ActionMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    alert('Click!');
  }

  render() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (button) =>
      React.cloneElement(button, {
        onClick: this.handleClick
      })
    );
  }
}

function ActionButton({ name, icon, onClick }) {
  return <button class={icon} onClick={onClick}>{name}</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use children regardless of whether it's a component of container.

"[children are] especially common for components like Sidebar or Dialog that represent generic 'boxes'."

In your case you have a menu, which falls into this category.

https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after. Actually you should just put the children in its closest parent instead of its `grandpa`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

function ActionButton({ name, handleClick }) {
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>{name}</button>
}

class ActionMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    alert('Click!');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ActionButton name="add" handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
        <ActionButton name="remove" handleClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ActionMenu />
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can try to run it in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7z1j7x02wq).

By the way, using `bind` is quite redundant now, we can use `public class fields syntax`, which is already [ECMA stage 2](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields).